# Enumerate with a range of numbers in an item's label

Tags: lists, numbering, enumerate

I am preparing an outline of lectures for a course.  Some topics will take more than one lecture.  I want to create an `enumerate` environment that reflects this.

I want to end up with something like

```
  1. Topic 1.
2-3. Topic 2.
  4. Topic 3.
5-6. Topic 4.
```

I know that I can do this manually, e.g.,

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item [1.] Topic 1.
    \item [2-3.] Topic 2.
    \item [4.] Topic 3.
    \item [5-6.] Topic 4.
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

However, if I want to insert another topic in the middle of the list, I need to re-do everything by hand.  Is there a way of doing this with one or more counters?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\itemrange#1{%
\addtocounter{enumi}{1}%
\edef\labelenumi{\theenumi--\noexpand\theenumi}%
\addtocounter{enumi}{-1}%
\addtocounter{enumi}{#1}%
\item
\def\labelenumi{\theenumi}}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item  Topic 1.
    \itemrange{1} Topic 2.
    \item  Topic 3.
    \itemrange{1} Topic 4.
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is a very nice solution.  I have one nitpick: an `itemrange` does not put a period after the label, and the same is true of any `item`s that occur after the first `itemrange`.

Comment: oh sorry just put a `.` at the end of the two definitions of `\labelenumi`.

Comment: Can this be altered to work in `\begin{enumerate*}` environments?

Comment: @L.Nielsen better to ask a new question as a new post rather than a comment on  a years old answer. Also please supply a test document in your question (there is no `enumerate*` environment by default)

Answer (score 0):

*Disclaimer: This is a personal variation. People are free to have difference of opinion on this.*

I would be doing it like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item  Topic 1
    \item  Topic 2
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item First session
        \item Second session
    \end{enumerate}
    \item  Topic 3
    \item  Topic 4
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item First session
        \item Second session
    \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]